# Какую роль играет Redux в этой связке Node+React+SCSS+Redux+Webpack?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, scss, webpack, redux

Друзья вопрос возник не на пустом месте.Недавно начал проектировать используя Node+React+Redux+Webpack, ну и кое что другое в их связке.Но в основном проблема в этой связке.То не так скомпилировал,то не так переменную назвал,то не там вызвал и т д .И вот решил разобраться с этим.

Помогите понять:

1. Kак понять эту связку,что за привилегии она нам даёт?
2. Если React это класс который реализует [Пользовательские элементы](https://learn.javascript.ru/webcomponent-core)
   ,тогда как понять что такое Redux и почему для его использования мне нужен Node.Это что Node - овская библиотека ?
3. И наконец Webpack.Он что socket использует?Насколько я понимаю для
   live update служат socket - и. И как вообще он понимает какой файл у
   нас изменён ?
4. И наконец расширение scss, это специальное разрешение,Node что получает содержимое в виде объекта ?

Если еще сузить кругозор то в принципе Redux очень непонятен.Можно ли как то простыми словами описать его,ну или элементарными примерами для  наглядности?

Спасибо.

Comment: знаю только о scss ето ксс препроцессор, оригинальное название sass, в scss синтаксис немного другой да и все...

Comment: Да но ты каким то образом можешь его содержимое получить в видe объекта.где селектор это ключ а остальное значение

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43450/discussion-on-question-by-vanya-avchyan----redux----n).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Это удобный стек для разработки приложений. Такой же, как, например, PHP + AngularJS. Никто не заставляет вас использовать именно его. Node можно заменить на Java, а SCSS на Stylus, например.
2. React - это не класс, а библиотека, которая позволяет написать View вашего приложения, не ограничивая явно в моделях и логике.

   Redux - это [иммутабельное](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82) хранилище состояния вашего приложения. Которое очень хорошо работает с React.

   И React и Redux можно использовать не только на клиенте, но и на сервере, (см. изоморфные приложения). React - для рендеринга на сервере, Redux - все для того же хранения состояния. Разумеется, для этого на сервере должен быть какой-то интерпретатор JS, обычно это NodeJS, но бывают отклонения.
3. Webpack среди прочего умеет работать в качестве вашего локального отладочного development-сервера, да еще и с живым обновлением кода в браузере. Так что да - без сокетов тут сложно.

   > И как вообще он понимает какой файл у нас изменён ?

   А как вы обычно понимаете, что файл был пересохранен? Наверное, смотрите дату изменения файла.
4. SCSS - это язык, компилирующийся (транслирующийся) в CSS.

Comment: На счет изменения файла.Это понятно.Получается он каждый раз по дереву пробегается что ли ? SCSS  каким образом он получает содержимого этого файла?То Есть он получает в виде объекта и подствляет тот или иной класс.Выглядит так  const scssObject= rquire('test.scss') и <MyTag className={scssObject.update_icon}/>

  то есть мы никуда  его не компилировали

Comment: 1. Не обязательно. Существуют хуки уровня операционной системы на изменение файлов. 2. Там все хитро, смотря как реализован конкретный loader для SCSS в webpack. Может и распарсить файл в объектное представление.

Comment: Парсинг SCSS по моему это нодовская фича.Сужу по этому коду const scssObject= rquire('test.scss')

Comment: Вы ошибаетесь, почитайте про [Webpack и его загрузчики](https://webpack.github.io/docs/loaders.html).

Comment: Все спасибо дальше сам  :)

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan каноническая реализация Sass/SCSS вообще на Ruby :) Но есть и другие реализации. Собственно, это лишь язык.